# create quadratic equation using Python library

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have data point on which I need to create quadratic equation.Do we have any python module which create quadratic equation.I have manual approach which is mentioned into below link.
but I feel it can be in better in Python.In below example, They have taken 3 point but In my
case it will varies as per the user input

http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/quadratic/Quadratic_Equations.faq.question.192159.html

Comment: How can it vary by user input? You cannot generate an exact quadratic equation with less than 3 points, and more than 3 points are useless because you get an equation with 3 points. So, you need exactly 3 points to generate an exact quadratic equation which satisfies those.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to solve mathematical equations in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642357/simplest-way-to-solve-mathematical-equations-in-python)

Comment: I have data in Excel sheet which I need to select and it may be 40 or 50 points and satisfy  them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at http://www.numpy.org/

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A, B, C = np.polyfit([1,2,3],[4,7,12],2)
>>> print A, B, C
1.0 -4.2727620148e-15 3.0
>>> print A, 'x^2 +', B, 'x +', C
1.0 x^2 + -4.2727620148e-15 x + 3.0
>>>
```